# Numpy/PyTorch break problem symmetry due to numeric precision

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form, python, machine-precision

In my problem, I apply a linear transformation to a Gaussian random variable $Y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, by multiplying it with a matrix $\mathbf{f} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, with $d<<n$.

With $\Sigma_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\Sigma_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ being the covariance matrices of the original and the transformed variable respectively, I am using the fact that, $\Sigma_2 = \mathbf{f}^T \Sigma_1 \mathbf{f}$ to compute $\Sigma_2$ in PyTorch, since $\Sigma_1$ is known and fixed, and I want to update $\Sigma_2$ as I learn $\mathbf{f}$.

From the above, we expect both $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ to be symmetric positive definite matrices (SPDMs). However, because of numeric precision, $\Sigma_2$ is slightly non-symmetric, with the difference in the values of symmetric elements being of the order `e-7` in PyTorch and `e-15` in Numpy. This is resulting in some inconveniences later on, since some operations complain about $\Sigma_2$ not being a SPDM.

I wonder if there is some work around to have $\Sigma_2$ be SPDM without necessarily having to fix the end result by hand, and without compromising much on computation speed.

I would also be interested in understanding a bit more how the asymmetries in the result originate, since it seems like elements $i,j$ and $j,i$ of the final matrix should originate from the exact same set of numbers.

Some code to reproduce this observation:

```
import numpy as np
n = 400
d = 5
A = np.random.randn(n, n)
Sigma1 = np.matmul(A, A.transpose()) * 0.01  # Symmetric positive definite matrix
f = np.random.randn(d, n) * 0.1  # Random filters
Sigma2 = np.einsum('kd,db,mb->km', f, Sigma1, f)  # Result of quadratic form
print(f'Symmetric residue of Sigma1: \n {Sigma1 - Sigma1.transpose()}')
print(f'Symmetric residue of Sigma2: \n {Sigma2 - Sigma2.transpose()}')
```

```
Symmetric residue of Sigma1: 
 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
Symmetric residue of Sigma2: 
 [[ 0.00000000e+00 -2.55351296e-15 -4.21884749e-15  1.11022302e-16
  -2.33146835e-15]
 [ 2.55351296e-15  0.00000000e+00 -3.33066907e-15  1.47104551e-15
   9.33975119e-15]
 [ 4.21884749e-15  3.33066907e-15  0.00000000e+00  1.14769305e-14
   8.88178420e-16]
 [-1.11022302e-16 -1.47104551e-15 -1.14769305e-14  0.00000000e+00
  -5.49560397e-15]
 [ 2.33146835e-15 -9.33975119e-15 -8.88178420e-16  5.49560397e-15
   0.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: $\Sigma_2’ = (\Sigma_2 + \Sigma_2^T)/2.$

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed more elegant than copy-pasting the elements, and should be efficient. The question aimed at some work around in how we compute the quadratic formula, maybe using some other algorithm to compute this, but perhaps what you propose is the simplest and most efficient solution.

Comment: You get this slight asymmetry because the computation of $(f^T\Sigma_1)f$ is not symmetric. Another correction would be to copy the elements below the diagonal to the corresponding places above the diagonal. In Python-numpy this would not be faster, in C/C++ this copying could be faster than the arithmetic operations which still have to copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more elegant then manual fix of the result, I believe increasing the accuracy of the computation, and then cutting the last few digits of the result may be good enough. For example,

```
A = np.float32(np.random.randn(n, n))
Sigma1 = np.float64(np.matmul(A, A.transpose()) * 0.01) # Symmetric positive definite matrix
f = np.float64(np.random.randn(d, n) * 0.1 ) # Random filters
Sigma2 = np.einsum('kd,db,mb->km', f, Sigma1, f)  # Result of quadratic form
Sigma2 = np.float32(Sigma2)
```

Should give a symmetric result.